# SQL Server Empty Result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a valid SQL select which returns an empty result, up and until a specific transaction has taken place in the environment.

Is there something available in SQL itself, that will allow me to return a 0 as opposed to an empty dataset? Similar to isNULL('', 0) functionality. Obviously I tried that and it didn't work.

PS. Sadly I don't have access to the database, or the environment, I have an agent installed that is executing these queries so I'm limited to solving this problem with just SQL.

FYI: Take any select and run it where the "condition" is not fulfilled (where LockCookie='777777777' for example.) If that condition is never met, the result is empty. But at some point the query will succeed based on a set of operations/tasks that happen. But I would like to return 0, up until that event has occurred.

Comment: can you post the code you are using?

Comment: Can you specify _until a specific transaction has taken place_?

Comment: John Woo, believe me there is no error in the SQL, as with an alternate post here @StackOverFlow. It's a simple select, no joins.

Comment: Tim, it means that there is no data available for the "where clause", until a set of tasks have completed, and then data is populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your result in a temp table and check `@@rowcount`.

```
select ID
into #T
from YourTable
where SomeColumn = @SomeValue

if @@rowcount = 0
  select 0 as ID
else
  select ID
  from #T

drop table #T
```

If you want this as one query with no temp table you can wrap *your* query in an `outer apply` against a dummy table with only one row.

```
select isnull(T.ID, D.ID) as ID
from (values(0)) as D(ID)
  outer apply
    (
      select ID
      from YourTable
      where SomeColumn = @SomeValue        
    ) as T
```

Answer (score 0):

alternet way is from code, you can check count of DataSet.

```
DsData.Tables[0].Rows.count > 0
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure that your query matches your conditions

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see this as answer. Please can you explain.

Comment: take the query to the SQL query editor and execute it there, if it outputs results, then the bug is in your code not the query